# What is the SQL Server equivalent of the following Access statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access

I have scoured stack overflow for this with no success.

I'm working on converting some access views, stored procedures, etc to SQL Server 2008.
[I am not very well versed in Access]

This is one statement that has me stumped:

```
IIf([Column1]=0,[Column2],[Column1])
```

Using the `SELECT CASE` statement, I can get the above statement suitably converted:

```
select case 
        when TABLE1.[COLUMN1]=0 then TABLE1.[COLUMN2]
    else TABLE1.[COLUMN1] 
    end as SomeColumn
```

...but this is also present in the GROUP BY clause.

That makes using `SELECT CASE` difficult since I can't have a subquery in `GROUP BY`.

Thoughts?

Comment: Can you use the `SomeColumn` alias in your GROUP BY clause?

Comment: SQL Server **2012** also has an `IIF` statement ....

Comment: I don't see what the problem is, you can put a case statement in the GROUP BY clause (and you have to, if it does not contain an aggregate function, when aggregate functions are used on other columns outside the CASE)

Comment: @RobertHarvey: The alias is not accepted in the group by clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no reason you can't put a CASE statement into the GROUP BY clause -

```
select case when TABLE1.[COLUMN1] = 0
            then TABLE1.[COLUMN2]
            else TABLE1.[COLUMN1] end as SomeColumn,
       another_col,
       canother_col2,
       sum(a_dif_col) as sum_a_col
from TABLE1
group by case when TABLE1.[COLUMN1] = 0
              then TABLE1.[COLUMN2]
              else TABLE1.[COLUMN1] end,
       another_col,
       canother_col2
```

The above is perfectly valid syntax.

Comment: Works. The column in the select case need not immediately precede the FROM command like you mentioned which I was unaware of. +1 for that

Answer (score 3):

You can use subquery:

```
SELECT data.Somecolumn
FROM (
    select case 
    when TABLE1.[COLUMN1]=0 then TABLE1.[COLUMN2]
    else TABLE1.[COLUMN1] 
    end as SomeColumn
) data
GROUP BY data.SomeColumn
```

Comment: that is very clever...  and simple

Answer (score 3):

It seems like you're under the impression that `select` is necessary before `case`. It is not. The following should work.

```
SELECT   CASE
            WHEN table1.column1 = 0 THEN table1.column2
            ELSE table1.column1
         END
            AS somecolumn
FROM     table1
GROUP BY CASE
            WHEN table1.column1 = 0 THEN table1.column2
            ELSE table1.column1
         END
```

Comment: I can only vote one answer as the accepted answer. Brian's answer demonstrated that the column i needed in the select case need not necessarily be the last one in the list. Although it wasn't mentioned as a requirement in my question, it turned out being important to me.